# ember js click action does not work from within button tag in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, button, ember.js, action

In the below code, #1(div) works fine but #2(button) doesn't in Internet Explorer. It however works fine in chrome

## 1

```
<div class="option-item btn btn-tag">
  Status: STATUS
  <span class="gel-icon-close" {{action "checkAction" }}></span>
</div>
```

## 2

```
<button class="option-item btn btn-tag">
  Status: STATUS
  <span class="gel-icon-close" {{action "checkAction" }}></span>
</button>
```

Just for reference: The controller has

```
actions: {
    checkAction: function (val) {
      window.alert('clicked' + val);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What version of IE? What version of Ember?

Comment: ember - 1.13.6 and IE-10, 9

Comment: Are you sure you're actually clicking the span inside the button? Have you tried logging `e.target`?

Comment: yes i am sure. e.target??? as far as i know we don't have access to event in ember actions

Comment: Can you build a JSBin or Ember-twiddle for this? I've experienced this problem and it's often been due to `display` styles. IE has certain obscure rules about making buttons and links clickable with non-default display values.